# Node.js appendFile username

Tags: node.js

I am using node 6.0. Here is the code. But Node.js does not recognize dollar sign("$")[why $ sign is not red?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sO912.png)

```
const os = require('os');
const fs = require('fs');
var user = os.userInfo();
fs.appendFile("message.txt","${user.username}")
```

I want write my username to message.txt

Comment: Use backticks `\`\`` not quotes `""`

Answer (score 2):

Use  ` instead of "

```
fs.appendFile("message.txt", `${ user.username }`)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

> Template literals are enclosed by the back-tick (` `)  ([grave accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent)) character instead of double or single quotes.

So you should use `` `${user.username}` `` instead of `"${user.username}"`.